# How to underline a Text upon clicking it?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to get my text displayed by "$item" underlined upon clicking by using onClick. I have used Divider() to create the underline and was trying to assign a default colour = background colour and blue upon clicking but the value of the variable underlineonclick does not change.

Edit: Solution by @BenjyTec worked. Thank you.

```
    //===========Rows for SECTIONS========================
        else {
        var underlineonclick:Color = bgwhite
        Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .paddingFromBaseline(5.dp, 5.dp)
        .clickable(onClick = {var underlineonclick:Color = neonblue}),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart
        ){
            Text(text = "S. " + "$corres_sec",
            fontSize = 14.sp,
            fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.hv_light)),
            fontWeight = FontWeight(650))
            Text(
            text = "$item",
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.hv_light)),
            fontWeight = FontWeight(650),
            modifier = Modifier.absolutePadding(left = 50.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify,
        ) }
        Box(Modifier.padding(top = 2.dp))
        {   Divider(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd),
            thickness = 3.dp,
            color = underlineonclick)}
        }
```

I have used Divider() to create the underline and was trying to assign a default colour = background colour and blue upon clicking but the value of the variable underlineonclick does not change. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your `onClick` function, you are creating a new variable named `underlineonclick` instead of modifying the existing `underlineonclick` variable. Also, in order to make your UI update when the value of `underlineonclick` changes, you need to use the `remember {}` keyword.

Please try to update your variable declaration at the top as follows:

```
var underlineonclick: Color by remember { mutableStateOf(bgwhite) }
```

Then change the `clickable` Modifier like this:

```
.clickable(onClick = { underlineonclick = neonblue })
```

---

Note: Also have a look at [`TextDecoration`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/glance/text/TextDecoration), it allows you to show an underline for text, although you cannot change the color of the underline:

```
Text(
    text = "Text with underline",
    style = TextStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline)
)
```